# Scipy odeint "The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got ndim=3"

Tags: python, scipy, controls, ode, odeint

i want to solve a problem with an ODE of a system, but im running into a problem that odeint says my functions return a ndims object. now im confused since i dont know what i did wrong.

i have tried `int(A[ 0 , 0 ])` for each elements. but it keeps returning a multidimensional array

Here's my code reduced to such but is able to run:

```
import numpy as np
import control
from scipy.integrate import odeint

#Now we write it in a numpy matrix with the following parameters:
k_1 = 1
k_2 = 1
k_3 = 1
k_4 = 1
k_5 = 1

m_x = 1
m_p = 1
m_y = 1

J = 1
r = 1

b_1 = 1
b_2 = 1

f_1 = 1
f_2 = 1

tau1 = 1
B_p = 1


A = np.matrix([[0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [(-4*k_1-f_1)/(m_x) , (-b_1)/(m_x) , 0 , 0 , (-k_1*r)/(m_x) , 0 , (-k_1*r)/(m_x) , 0 , (k_1*r)/(m_x) , 0 , (k_1*r)/(m_x) , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , (-2*k_2-2*k_5)/(4*m_p+m_x+m_y) , (-b_2-f_2)/(4*m_p+m_x+m_y) , k_2*r/(4*m_p+m_x+m_y) , 0 , k_2*r/(4*m_p+m_x+m_y) , 0 , k_5*r/(4*m_p+m_x+m_y) , 0 , -k_5*r/(4*m_p+m_x+m_y) , 0 , -k_5*r/(4*m_p+m_x+m_y) , 0 , -k_5*r/(4*m_p+m_x+m_y) , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [(-k_1*r)/(J) , 0 , (k_2*r)/(J) , 0 , (-k_1*r**2-k_2*r**2-tau1)/(J) , (-B_p)/(J) , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [(-k_1*r)/(J) , 0 , (-k_2*r)/(J) , 0 , 0 , 0 , (-k_1*r**2-k_2*r**2-tau1)/(J) , (-B_p)/(J) , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0  ],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [(k_1*r)/(J) , 0 , (k_5*r)/(J) , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , (-k_1*r**2-k_5*r**2-tau1)/(J) , (-B_p)/(J) , 0 , 0 , (k_5*r**2)/(J) , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0  ],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [(k_1*r)/(J) , 0 , (-k_5*r)/(J) , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , (-k_1*r**2-k_5*r**2-tau1)/(J) , (-B_p)/(J) , 0 , 0 , (k_5*r**2)/(J) , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0  ],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , (-k_5*r)/(J) , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , (k_5*r**2)/(J) , 0 , 0 , 0 , (-k_4*r**2-k_5*r**2-tau1)/(J) , (-B_p)/(J) , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , (k_4*r**2)/(J) , 0 ],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , (k_5*r)/(J) , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , (k_5*r**2)/(J) , 0 , 0 , 0 , (-k_4*r**2-k_5*r**2-tau1)/(J) , (-B_p)/(J) , (k_4*r**2)/(J) , 0 , 0 , 0  ],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , (k_4*r**2)/(J) , 0 , (-k_3*r**2-k_4*r**2-tau1)/(J) , (-B_p)/(J) , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , (k_4*r**2)/(J) , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , (-k_3*r**2-k_4*r**2-tau1)/(J) , (-B_p)/(J)],])

B = np.matrix([[0, 0],
               [0, 0],
               [0, 0],
               [k_2*r, -k_2*r],
               [0, 0],
               [-k_2*r**2, 0],
               [0, 0],
               [0, -k_2*r**2],
               [0, 0],
               [0, 0],
               [0, 0],
               [0, 0],
               [0, 0],
               [0, 0],
               [0, 0],
               [0, 0],
               [0, 0],
               [k_3*r**2, 0],
               [0, 0],
               [0, k_3*r**2]])



# This Q matrix penalize the user for bad performance, we know its

Q1 = 1 #Penalize wrong position of x
Q2 = 1 #Penalize wrong position of xdot
Q3 = 1 #Penalize wrong position of y
Q4 = 1 #Penalize wrong position of ydot
Q5 = 1
Q6 = 1
Q7 = 1
Q8 = 1
Q9 = 1
Q10 = 1
Q11 = 1
Q12 = 1
Q13 = 1
Q14 = 1
Q15 = 1
Q16 = 1
Q17 = 1
Q18 = 1
Q19 = 1
Q20 = 1

Q = np.matrix([[Q1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , Q2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , Q3 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , Q4 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q5 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q6 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q7 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q8 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q9 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q10 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q11 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q12 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q13 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q14 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q15 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q16 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q17 , 0 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q18 , 0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q19 , 0],
               [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , Q20]])

R1 = 1
R2 = 1

R = np.matrix([[R1 , 0],
               [0 , R2 ]])


D = np.matrix([[0 , 0],
               [0 , 0 ]])
K, S, E = control.lqr(A, B, Q, R)

A = A-B*K

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
#kondisi awal
S_0 = np.matrix([[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]])
#kondisi tujuan
u = np.matrix([[50], [0], [50], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]])
u = -K*(S_0 - u)
M1 = u[0]
M2 = u[1]
S_0 = [0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

def X(S,t,M1,M2,A,B):
#   X  Xdot Y Ydot  P3  P3D P4 P4D  P5  P5D  P6   P6D
    Z1, Z2, Z3, Z4, Z5, Z6, Z7, Z8, Z9, Z10, Z11, Z12, Z13, Z14, Z15, Z16, Z17, Z18, Z19, Z20 = S

    J = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    J[0] = A[ 0 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 0 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 0 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 0 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 0 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 0 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 0 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 0 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 0 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 0 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 0 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 0 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 0 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 0 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 0 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 0 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 0 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 0 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 0 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 0 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 0 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 0 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[1] = A[ 1 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 1 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 1 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 1 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 1 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 1 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 1 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 1 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 1 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 1 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 1 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 1 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 1 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 1 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 1 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 1 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 1 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 1 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 1 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 1 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 1 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 1 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[2] = A[ 2 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 2 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 2 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 2 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 2 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 2 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 2 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 2 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 2 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 2 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 2 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 2 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 2 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 2 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 2 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 2 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 2 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 2 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 2 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 2 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 2 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 2 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[3] = A[ 3 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 3 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 3 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 3 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 3 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 3 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 3 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 3 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 3 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 3 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 3 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 3 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 3 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 3 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 3 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 3 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 3 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 3 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 3 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 3 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 3 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 3 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[4] = A[ 4 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 4 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 4 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 4 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 4 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 4 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 4 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 4 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 4 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 4 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 4 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 4 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 4 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 4 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 4 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 4 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 4 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 4 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 4 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 4 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 4 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 4 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[5] = A[ 5 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 5 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 5 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 5 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 5 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 5 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 5 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 5 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 5 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 5 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 5 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 5 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 5 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 5 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 5 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 5 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 5 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 5 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 5 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 5 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 5 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 5 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[6] = A[ 6 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 6 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 6 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 6 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 6 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 6 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 6 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 6 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 6 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 6 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 6 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 6 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 6 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 6 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 6 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 6 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 6 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 6 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 6 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 6 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 6 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 6 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[7] = A[ 7 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 7 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 7 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 7 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 7 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 7 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 7 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 7 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 7 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 7 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 7 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 7 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 7 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 7 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 7 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 7 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 7 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 7 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 7 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 7 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 7 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 7 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[8] = A[ 8 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 8 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 8 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 8 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 8 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 8 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 8 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 8 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 8 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 8 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 8 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 8 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 8 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 8 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 8 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 8 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 8 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 8 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 8 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 8 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 8 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 8 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[9] = A[ 9 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 9 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 9 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 9 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 9 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 9 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 9 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 9 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 9 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 9 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 9 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 9 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 9 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 9 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 9 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 9 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 9 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 9 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 9 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 9 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 9 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 9 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[10] = A[ 10 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 10 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 10 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 10 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 10 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 10 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 10 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 10 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 10 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 10 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 10 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 10 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 10 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 10 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 10 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 10 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 10 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 10 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 10 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 10 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 10 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 10 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[11] = A[ 11 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 11 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 11 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 11 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 11 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 11 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 11 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 11 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 11 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 11 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 11 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 11 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 11 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 11 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 11 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 11 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 11 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 11 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 11 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 11 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 11 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 11 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[12] = A[ 12 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 12 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 12 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 12 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 12 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 12 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 12 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 12 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 12 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 12 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 12 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 12 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 12 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 12 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 12 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 12 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 12 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 12 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 12 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 12 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 12 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 12 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[13] = A[ 13 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 13 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 13 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 13 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 13 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 13 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 13 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 13 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 13 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 13 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 13 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 13 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 13 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 13 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 13 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 13 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 13 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 13 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 13 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 13 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 13 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 13 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[14] = A[ 14 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 14 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 14 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 14 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 14 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 14 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 14 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 14 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 14 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 14 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 14 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 14 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 14 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 14 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 14 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 14 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 14 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 14 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 14 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 14 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 14 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 14 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[15] = A[ 15 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 15 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 15 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 15 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 15 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 15 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 15 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 15 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 15 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 15 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 15 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 15 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 15 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 15 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 15 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 15 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 15 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 15 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 15 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 15 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 15 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 15 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[16] = A[ 16 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 16 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 16 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 16 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 16 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 16 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 16 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 16 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 16 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 16 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 16 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 16 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 16 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 16 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 16 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 16 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 16 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 16 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 16 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 16 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 16 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 16 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[17] = A[ 17 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 17 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 17 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 17 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 17 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 17 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 17 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 17 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 17 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 17 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 17 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 17 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 17 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 17 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 17 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 17 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 17 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 17 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 17 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 17 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 17 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 17 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[18] = A[ 18 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 18 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 18 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 18 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 18 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 18 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 18 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 18 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 18 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 18 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 18 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 18 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 18 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 18 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 18 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 18 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 18 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 18 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 18 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 18 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 18 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 18 , 1 ]*M2,
    J[19] = A[ 19 , 0 ]*Z1 + A[ 19 , 1 ]*Z2 + A[ 19 , 2 ]*Z3 + A[ 19 , 3 ]*Z4 + A[ 19 , 4 ]*Z5 + A[ 19 , 5 ]*Z6 + A[ 19 , 6 ]*Z7 + A[ 19 , 7 ]*Z8 + A[ 19 , 8 ]*Z9 + A[ 19 , 9 ]*Z10 + A[ 19 , 10 ]*Z11 + A[ 19 , 11 ]*Z12 + A[ 19 , 12 ]*Z13 + A[ 19 , 13 ]*Z14 + A[ 19 , 14 ]*Z15 + A[ 19 , 15 ]*Z16 + A[ 19 , 16 ]*Z17 + A[ 19 , 17 ]*Z18 + A[ 19 , 18 ]*Z19 + A[ 19 , 19 ]*Z20 + B[ 19 , 0 ]*M1 + B[ 19 , 1 ]*M2

    print(J)

    return J


X = odeint(func=X, y0=S_0, t=t,args=(M1,M2,A,B),full_output=True)
```

and here's my output and traceback call (the print output was from my debugging)

```
[(matrix([[0.]]),), (matrix([[0.]]),), (matrix([[0.]]),), (matrix([[73.30572786]]),), (matrix([[5.]]),), (matrix([[-39.25352255]]),), (matrix([[0.]]),), (matrix([[32.38553864]]),), (matrix([[0.]]),), (matrix([[5.]]),), (matrix([[0.]]),), (matrix([[-5.]]),), (matrix([[0.]]),), (matrix([[-5.]]),), (matrix([[0.]]),), (matrix([[5.]]),), (matrix([[0.]]),), (matrix([[39.25352255]]),), (matrix([[0.]]),), matrix([[-37.38553864]])]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Program\DynamicsAnalysis\test3.py", line 171, in <module>
    X = odeint(func=X, y0=S_0, t=t,args=(M1,M2,A,B),full_output=True)
  File "C:\Users\Richie Ryu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_odepack_py.py", line 241, in odeint
    output = _odepack.odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, ml, mu,
RuntimeError: The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got ndim=3.
PS F:\Program\DynamicsAnalysis>
```

I have tried making sure that A elements are integers by using int().
I have tried moving the matrix A and B used in the ODE to be inside the function.
I have tried reading and searching the web for the Traceback and well maybe my searching skill isnt up to par if the answer is out there

Comment: Do a test call of `X`, with the values it would get at the initial conditions: `X(S_0, 0, M1, M2, A, B)`.  What does it return?  Is it the 1d array that `odeint` expects.  Focus on the your variables, and on the `odeint` docs, not on some sort of wild Web search.

Comment: Or look at what the `print(J)` showed.  I assume it got that far.  Did you look at it?  you forgot to show it to us!

Comment: Your use of `np.matrix` might be a problem.  `A` and `B` are `np.matrix`, but you index them with `[0,1]`, so that's a scalar result.  But what's the shape of `M1` and `M2`. They are derived from `u`, a `np.matrix`.  So they are 2d.

Comment: The "answer isn't out there" because other people aren't making the same mistake as you.  When you have problems with dimensions, look at the dimensions of the inputs, and trace them through your code.  `int` values has nothing to do with this; nor is there an issue with how you pass `A,B` to the function.  Focus on understanding the source of the problem.  Don't try "random" fixes that have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Thanks paul, i though that it was kinda weird that the value returned by M1 is 'M1 =  [[41.91520761]]' so one of my problems are I'm passing a 2d input.

ok I have tried cal,ling the function x, and well it returns a python array:
'Value of X is =  [(0.0,), (0.0,), (0.0,), (73.30572785825336,), (5.0,), (-39.25352254723535,), (0.0,), (32.38553864435136,), (0.0,), (5.0,), (0.0,), (-5.0,), (0.0,), (-5.0,), (0.0,), (5.0,), (0.0,), (39.25352254723535,), (0.0,), -37.38553864435136]'
do u need to add like J[0][0] at the function return?

thanks

Comment: oh wait i know the problem now paul thanks to you. my code before didn't use J and just return the function and I still left the `,` at the end making the every element of J a tuple. my bad my problem was the u in the first place.